# Is unpublished app still available for internal testers on PlayStore?

Tags: android, google-play

We have a dev version of our app that we never uploaded on the store as a Production app, only as an internal app for testers.

Today I mistakenly uploaded it to Production, so I toggled it to Unpublished for it not to be visible for all Android users.

But now I'm wondering if we will still be able to use our internal process despite it will remain unpublished?

Comment: Just delete that production version. Do not use unpublish.

Comment: @Style-7 You can't delete it, can you?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they have access to the app. They can test it by the link in the AppTester segment

Comment: If the version is unpublished, it seems you cannot access it even as a tester.

Answer (score 0):

yes for that we have alpha in which you can give only for tester

Comment: If the version is unpublished, it seems you cannot access it even as a tester.

Comment: no please update for alpha so you can do that or you can even use firebase distribution for the same as well